# Function not working properly inside loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a code that is supposed to get the elements from a ListBox and roll them trough a code that tries every value from there until it finds the correct one (using WebBrowser):

```
 Public Function ParseWordList() As String
 Dim count As Integer
        For count = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            Dim l_text As String = CStr(ListBox2.Items(count))
            Return l_text
        Next
    End Function
```

*Also tell me if even this function is wrong somehow

Main one, using this other func posted before:

```
  Private Sub Timer9_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer9.Tick
        If docCompleted2 Then Exit Sub
        Button3.Enabled = True
        Do
            ProgressBar2.Value = 0
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            If docCompleted2 Then docCompleted2 = False
            If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtLoginID") IsNot Nothing Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtLoginID").SetAttribute("value", TextBox5.Text)
            End If
            Dim gen2 As String
            gen2 = ParseWordList()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(gen2)
            If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtPassword") IsNot Nothing Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tbtPassword").SetAttribute("value", gen2)
            End If
            If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("div_123") IsNot Nothing Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("rockLogin")
            End If
            ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value + 50
            ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
            ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value + 50
            If Integer.TryParse(Label5.Text, intValue1) Then
                intTotal = intValue1
            End If
            intValue1 = intValue1 + 1
            Label5.Text = intValue1
            docCompleted2 = True
            If docCompleted2 = True Then
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("hidden")
                WaitForPageLoad()
                WaitMate()
                Label1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("nickName").GetAttribute("innerText")
            Else
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("hidden")
                WaitForPageLoad()
                WaitMate()
                Label1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("nickName").GetAttribute("innerText")
                ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value + 50
                If Integer.TryParse(Label5.Text, intValue1) Then
                    intTotal = intValue1
                End If
                intValue1 = intValue1 + 1
                Label5.Text = intValue1
                ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1
                ProgressBar2.Value = ProgressBar2.Value + 50
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub
```

What error I get? Nothing, its just that the function only uses the first element in the listbox and i want it to use all of them one after another but i dont know how to do that or even what to search for.

Don't blame me if the title is wrong or if I'm not focusing on the right points, I have 0 idea what is wrong and believe me I tried a lot of stuff before coming here :(

Comment: WHat is the loop supposed to do..it only ever looks at item 3 if it even exists.

Comment: The loop will only execute if there are more than 3 things in the list; then the function is written to return - exit the loop and return the string - for the first item it looks at. UI COntrols are a bad way to store data; use a list of some sort where you can persist an index variable

Comment: It is just me... I don't see ParseWordList in the timer handler?

Comment: Nope, I fixed what was wrong, I was experimenting with some things but now it is back as it should be, you should look over it again, soray :(

Comment: The loop still does nothing... there is no test in there so it always returns on the first pass. What is it SUPPOSED  to do?

Comment: `ParseWordList` doesnt parse anything.  Change it to `Function GetNextItem(index As int32) As String`  Keep and pass a variable for the one to get ...same as `ListBox2.Items(ndxVar)` though so the function is pointless

Comment: @Trevor Get elements from listbox and put them in SetAttribute("value", RIGHT_HERE) like I said

Comment: @Plutonix not sure what you mean but thanks anyway

Comment: BUt it only ever returns one element... Get by WHAT criteria?

Comment: @Plutonix is saying, if all you are doings is retrieving subsequent list items per do loop simply increment a counter in your loop and fetch the item using Listbox2.Items(<Your counter name>)

Comment: @Trevor Q1: Just first to last lol Q2: Tried that before but didnt help (or at least something like that if i understand it right)

Comment: Well that WILL retrieve one word per pass. However, what happens after that.... I don't know, though I don't see an exit from that do loop so you maybe stuck in an infinite loop that never returns. ME thinks you need to change the do loop to the For count = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1 .....and use the previous comment to retrieve the value.

Comment: I'll go try and come back with the results

Comment: This would be an *excellent* chance to learn to use the debugger and how code executes as part of it.  Set a break point and step thru the code to see what really happens.  You will want to change a large part of the code once you do.

Comment: Err doesn't the loop only run once? Surely the `Return` statement exits the function immediately.